# Massive MSreplcommands table, 2 billion rows, cleanup job not deleting commands

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a runaway distribution database that is 640gb in size. I have narrowed it down to the `msreplcommands` table which is holding 2 billion rows.

I have checked all publications and found 2 of them having immediate sync set to 1. I changed this to 0. Reran the cleanup job and it deleted about 240K rows only. Ran this:

```
SELECT *  from MSrepl_transactions (nolock) where entry_time < getdate() -5;
```

Found entries as old as 30 days.

The problem is I am running out of space very fast and all delete attempts lock the `msreplcommands` table and thus lock replication. We are a 24/7 shop and I have no server downtime possible. Is there another way to delete this amount of data without locking replication?

Hi T.H, Thanks for the suggestion. I found that link earlier and decided to try it. I've done some investigating and found very old entries in the MSrepl_transactions table going back 32 days using the following query:

SELECT distinct cast(entry_time as date) as entry_time, publisher_database_id, xact_seqno, count(publisher_database_id) FROM [distribution].[dbo].MSrepl_transactions group by entry_time, publisher_database_id, xact_seqno order by entry_time

Comment: Have you tried the process at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrissk/2009/12/29/how-to-resolve-when-distribution-database-is-growing-huge-25gig/? Or are you saying even those built-in commands lock the table in an unacceptable way?

Comment: Hi T.H. I used the link you posted and modified the statement:

Comment: But have you tried the SP call of which there is an example in step 8? In your case to first try to get rid of anything older than 30 days you would specify max_distretention = 720.

Comment: I used the link you posted and found transactions older than 32 days. I modified the statement:  max_distretention = 744 

I've run it and its been running now for 7 hour and 40 min without locking but hasn't completed. Commands are still going up. Sorry for bad formatting first time posting here.

Comment: Hey T.H. Update!!   At exactly the 8 hour mark the commands are starting to decrease in MSrepl_commands!  HURRAY! Thanks. It is going very slowly but its also looking through a 2 billion row table. Its also not locking anything! I'll keep monitoring and add another update here later.

Comment: Nice, hopefully the slow deletions can stay ahead of the inserts. I've added an answer I hope can be accepted once you confirm it's all working.

Comment: Well I guess you didn't need help by the time I came along, but I did try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chrissk/2009/12/29/how-to-resolve-when-distribution-database-is-growing-huge-25gig/ can help with this.

To prevent it happening in future you may need to look at the configuration of the *Distribution clean up: distribution* job.